# Azure Web Deploy publishing old version of MVC sites .dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, dll

I deploy my MVC site via a web publish within VS 2013 to an Azure location. I have published many times without issue from the same machine and IP address, but yesterday it stopped working.

The publish is placing an old version of my projects .dll in the bin folder on the site. This version no longer exists on my machine, it isn't the projects current Git state (and has never been the current Git state) and is not the version in my Release, Debug or Demo compiled folder. I don't know where it's coming from.

So when I publish, I get errors relating to the database changes because the model behind my context has changed since this old version.

So currently when I publish I have to FTP into my site and replace the WebPortal.dll file with the one in my machines bin folder, and the the site works fine.

What could be causing it to revert to this old .dll and where is it coming from? Have I somehow excluded my changes past a certain point from the publish?

Note - My views are publishing absolutely fine, it is just the .dll that should contain the current compilation of Models, Controllers etc., but instead contains an old version missing loads of stuff.

JK

Answer (score 3):

There might be an old version of your dll on the server that is not being overwritten during publish. Have you tried checking "Remove additional files at destination" the the settings section of the Publish dialog. That should remove all the files from your target location except the one you publish.

If you are still having a problem after that try publishing to your local file system so you can see exactly what publish is sending to your server.

[image]

**Update:**

Steps to publish web application to file system.

1. right click on your project in the solution explorer menu and select Publish.
2. In the profile section of the Publish Web menu select Custom publish type, click next.
3. Select file system in the Publish method drop-down. You should see the target location text box where you can specify your folder.
4. Continue with the rest of the publish steps with you usual settings and click publish.

Comment: Hi. I have tried that yes. I've also tried an FTP publish with the box checked to remove ALL files on the server. After manually overwriting the old .dll with my new one any old .dll should have gone anyway right? The old .dll is coming from my computer somewhere....How do I publish to a local file system?

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill I have added the steps to publish to file system to my answer

Comment: Thanks. Publishing to a local folder gives the same result. And old version of the WebPortal.dll. It must be something in the compilation of the project during publishing as the WebPortal.dll of that size does not exist on my computer anywhere and when I build normally it build the new .dll correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your Build (Menu) > Configuration Manager > Build Configuration for Release has the tick next to Build for the WebPortal.DLL. If it isn't set to build then it would use an older version.

Comment: Yes, the tick is there for it to build the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Goodness knows where the old dll is coming from but in the end I up-versioned the library to a higher number and it seemed to cure it. I suspect the GAC or temporary files might be part of the problem although I can't find my library there.